# How to change SVG filter dynamically using JavaScript or CSS?

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-filters

I want to change an SVG filter dynamically, to use the mouse position or other variables.

Here's an example:

```js
let filter = document.getElementById("myFilterOffset");
document.addEventListener("mousemove", ev => {
  let viewportMouseX = ev.clientX / window.innerWidth;
  filter.setAttribute("dx", Math.floor(viewportMouseX * 500));
});
```

```css
div {
  filter: url(#myFilter);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
      <filter id="myFilter">
      <feOffset id="myFilterOffset" dx="0" dy="0">
      </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div>Hello!</div>
```

The first time the code runs it actually works, but only the first time. All subsequent calls just do nothing, even though in the Chrome DevTools I can see the attribute actually still changing.
Do I somehow have to force a redraw or something like that? If so, how?

I also thought of using CSS to target #myFilterOffset and binding a CSS variable to the 'dx' property and then change the CSS variable using JavaScript, but that didn't work either since it seems it's not possible to change the dx attribute using CSS.

Edit: Forgot to mention I only tested this in Chrome. Seems to be a bug, I guess.

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? I mean using SVG is an absolute requirement?

Comment: I want to create a chrome extension for fun that changes the look of each webpage. Specifically a chromatic aberration effect that is weaker at the mouse position but gets stronger the further away from the mouse something is. I figured applying a custom SVG filter to the body element would be the best approach.

Comment: It seems to work in Firefox.

Comment: Report Chrome bugs to Chrome's bugtracker unless the bug already exists there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const filter = document.getElementById("myFilterOffset");
const svg = document.getElementById("test");
document.addEventListener("mousemove", ev => {
  let viewportMouseX = ev.clientX / window.innerWidth;
  filter.setAttribute("dx", Math.floor(viewportMouseX * 500));
  svg.setAttribute("width","0");
});
```

```css
div {
  filter: url(#myFilter);
}
```

```html
<svg id="test" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
      <filter id="myFilter">
      <feOffset id="myFilterOffset" in="SourceGraphic" dx="0" dy="0">
      </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div id="svg">Hello!</div>
```

your dx attribute changing successfully but it will not re-render. You need to trigger the re-render by simply setting the width of SVG.

Comment: You're saying this is a Chrome bug and providing a workaround? This would seem not to be required on other browsers and presumably on Chrome if this bug gets fixed.

Comment: There are problems with svg render on chrome and UC Browser. Better be sure with your solution then gambling on browser.